# JSON Parse Error in MongoDB and R

Tags: r, mongodb, shiny, rmongo

I am new to R and MongoDB and everything related to programming so please bear with me. I am trying to query a MongoDB database based on user input (dropdown menu). When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Error: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
       {'Name':input$prod}
               ^
```

Here is my UI:

```
mydb <- mongoDbConnect("mysearch")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("MYsearch"),
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("prod", label = "Choose my Product/Service", 
        choices = list("Engineering", "Operations",
                       "Detection"), selected = "Engineering")
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("table1"))
    )
))
```

Here is my server:

```
my <- mongoDbConnect("mysearch")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- renderTable({ 
          dbGetQuery(mydb, "usercollection", "{'Name':input$prod}")
     })
}
)
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
queryParam <- paste('{\'Name\':', input$prod, '}');

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- renderTable({ 
          dbGetQuery(mydb, "usercollection", queryParam)
     })
}
)
```

Instead of passing the value stored in input$prod, you are passing the string "input$prod" to the function.